# No Runnable methods Error From Base Test class

Tags: spring, junit, intellij-idea

I have a A few base test classes that setup common configurations for spring,logging,jndi etc using test execution listeners that are then inherited by subclasses. This is done so tests can just run code without having to worry about getting jndi and logging services in place before being able to run testing code.

Using intellij and invoking "run all tests" from the project base, the IDE attempts to run the base test class as a unit test and gives me the "No runnable methods" error.

I know I could put an empty runnable method in the base class, but I was hoping some one has a better idea.

The Base class is:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {
            "classpath:spring-jndi.xml"
    })
    @TestExecutionListeners({
            Log4JSetupListener.class,
            JndiSetupListener.class,
            DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
            DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
            TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
    })
    public class SpringAppTestCase extends Assert implements ApplicationContextAware {

        protected JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();

        @Autowired
        protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) {
            this.applicationContext = ac;
        }

    // 
    //    @Test
    //    public void doit(){
    //      // this would prevent blow up but 
    // all subclass tests would run an extra method
    //    }

        protected Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

}
```

The error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateInstanceMethods(MethodValidator.java:32)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.validate(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:36)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
```

Comment: Actually there are not tests in the code above.... You have it commented out so the error message is correct?

Comment: Yes, explained by the comment inside the commented code

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Make the parent class `abstract` or rename it such as it does not end in `Test` or `TestCase`.

Comment: Thanks!  I had my class starting with "Test" and that caused the same issue.

Comment: Thanks too! I had almost the same problem except that I had a class that was NOT a class test but with a name starting by Test, and that led to the same error message.

Comment: Taking "Test" out of the class name didn't work for me. But adding "abstract" did.

Answer (score 16):

making sure the @Test annotation import is org.junit.Test and not something else like juniper which i saw as a comment by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977017/no-runnable-methods-error-from-base-test-class/39721930#comment106724436_39721930) worked for me. Wanted to add this as an answer so it can be seen by others

Comment: `org.junit.Test` is JUnit4, `org.junit.jupiter.api` is JUnit5. More info for [migrating @RunWith](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith).

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. I was testing without a Test method.

```
@Test
public void setupTest() {
}
```

Above method solved the issue.

Comment: This empty test will run x number times as any subclass inherit it (for no reason). The accepted answer gives 2 better options.

Comment: I did the same mistake

Comment: Or make sure the `@Test` annotation import is `org.junit.Test` and not something else like juniper

Comment: I was using the wrong import `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` instead of `import org.junit.Test;`. Your answer pointed me to verify that import, cheers!

Comment: if there is a base class, it has to be a `abstract` class and there must be at least one `@Test` - Junit4, SpringBoot 2.0

Answer (score 2):

I Got the same problem but I had no class inheritance and `@Test` annotation was present. Problem was that my test class was public, I deleted `public` modifier and problem was fixed.

Comment: Many reasons I could have this issues were described, but i felt in the most elementary error, your answer just pointed it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do not mix JUnit4 and JUnit5.

For example try to use `@BeforeEach`  (from JUnit5) instead of `@Before` (from JUnit4) etc.

And make sure your `@Test` annotation is imported from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that you are not importing the @Test from Jupiter, mixing the JUnit 4 and JUnit 5, can cause the same issue. I imported the right JUnit for my SpringRunner and the problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my test class is not public.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29802829)

Answer (score 0):

I made the base unit test class an abstract class. Then Junit no longer sees it as a test class.

Comment: This has already been stated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, spring boot with JUnit 5, I use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)  along with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class), remove @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) fixed it.