# Specific JUnit Test Faliure in a IntelliJ Maven Project

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, intellij-idea

I'm working on a java project using IntelliJ. The project requires the use of some external libraries located in directories outside the project. Most of the code has been written by another author, I am simply expanding the functionality of the current program. The problem comes from one of the test cases for one of the external libraries (which was written by the original author). **While these test cases pass successfully when I use -mvn test command in terminal, they fail when run in IntelliJ.**

The error/failiure output is as follows

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods <13 internal calls>
```

for all 15 tests

I've checked to make sure that the @Before annotation is before any @test annotations tests, and all the required tests have the @Test annotation before them.

Why would JUnit tests fail to run when they run and pass succesfully with the Maven Surefire Plugin?

I am using junit 4.1.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977017

Comment: Possibly, but I emailed the author about it, and they said that the test cases ran fine on their workstation. So I'm wondering if its how I setup the project?

Comment: Although I would usually ask the author directly via skype, they live in a timezone 13 hours behind mine, I just figured to save some time banging my head against the wall,  someone might have encountered a similar problem.

Comment: Are you sure that IntelliJ uses the same JUnit-related libraries/versions as the ones specified in your pom.xml?

Comment: yes both use 4.1 in this manner <artifactId>junit</<artifactId> <version>4.1</version>

Comment: also in intelliJ junit 4.1 is listed in the external libraries as being present in the maven repository

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but the junit tests run fine for a different external library (called sbml) its just this one (cellml) that the junit tests fail for.

Comment: Post your Maven settings for the surefire plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah problem solved. Quite a while ago actually. In IntelliJ, sometimes you need to set up VM Options with the `-Djava.library.path = /(path to your lib files)/` as well as configure Environment variables by creating a variable --> LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /(path to required .so files)/

All tests run fine now.